# Authenticate a user against an untrusted domain

Tags: .net, authentication, dns, ldap

I have to implement an authentication system in our ASP.NET web application, so that users can Login and check their credentials against the Windows AD (or a Unix Directory service, I don't know which exactly) in their specific untrusted Domain.

Can this even be done? Do you have a keyword for me, which technology I could use?

Answer (score 0):

if i'm right you need to do an LDAP authentication (http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/whatisldap.html). These are some links which might help you

http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource6-Login-authentication-using-LDAP-Active-Directory-for-ASPNET-applications.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180890(v=vs.80).aspx